# What does it means "to get us by"?

Tags: meaning

Reading a article I've noticed the phrase in the sentence which i don't understand.
here's this sentence "A lot of us like a small, sleek computer case **to get us by** but such a case can be extremely hard to find".
What is this "to get us by"?
Please explain the meaning of this phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of the phrasal verb "get by", meaning to "meet the minimum requirements" to survive or accomplish something.

In your sentence, it effectively means, "A lot of us like a small, sleek computer case *to meet our need to enclose our computer without any extra features* but such a case can be extremely hard to find".

Your sentence appears on a website that confirms this meaning: it also says that the case "supports the bare minimum of computer" and describes the cases as having ["no flashy bells and whistles"](https://www.overclockersclub.com/reviews/lian_li35/) (archived at [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200806091315/https://www.overclockersclub.com/reviews/lian_li35/)), showing that the cases provide basic requirements, but nothing extra.

Comment: i wonder the phrasal verb includes someone between words. is it grammatically right? In a dictionary i meet without someone between only.

Comment: You are right that, strictly speaking, "get by" is an intransitive phrasal verb that cannot include someone. In practice, this rule is sometimes broken.

Comment: Colloquially, the verb can be transitive: Glasgow Times: *And Denis Curran, chairman at the charity, said: "The idea with the foodbank is to try to give people enough to get them by. People are hungry.* https://www.glasgowtimes.co.uk/news/18037775.celtic-ace-leigh-griffiths-volunteers-foodbank-christmas-appeal/ Alien Guitar Lessons for the Intermediate & Advanced Guitarist By Denis Taaffe *I was in demand because I knew the A blues scale and it got me by in some of these early bands.*